# Data record becomes double in database when updated

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have 2 features that I'm working on, say Clock in and Clock out. The thing is that when I clock out(updated the Time Clock out and Location Clock out), suddenly there's an extra record as seen on this pic, https://paste.pics/586336ef0bf2517da832678425125655 . Although the data is updated but there's an extra row with an updated info in 'time_checkOut' and 'location_checkOut'. I am wondering what is wrong here ?

I tried inserting and updating the data by *injecting* time manually by using the code below before and it's working just fine as seen on the screenshot picture above but when I am using Carbon::now() and update the info using this. The data table in the database will double when I *clock out*.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$date = $r->date_checkIn;
$time = date('H:i:s');
$time = $r->time_checkIn;
```

Below are my 2 controllers :

```
public function userClockIn(Request $r)
    {
        $result = [];
        $result['status'] = false;
        $result['message'] = "something error";

        $users = User::where('staff_id', $r->staff_id)->select(['staff_id', 'date_checkIn', 'time_checkIn', 'location_checkIn'])->first();

        $mytime = Carbon::now();
        $date = $mytime->format('Y-m-d');
        $time = $mytime->format('H:i:s');

        $users->date_checkIn = $date;
        $users->time_checkIn = $time;
        $users->location_checkIn = $r->location_checkIn;

        $users->save();

        // Retrieve current data
        $currentData = $users->toArray();

        // Store current data into attendace record table
        $attendanceRecord = new AttendanceRecord();
        $attendanceRecord->fill($currentData);
        $attendanceRecord->save();

        $result['data'] = $users;
        $result['status'] = true;
        $result['message'] = "suksess add data";

        return response()->json($result);
    }

public function userClockOut(Request $r)
    {
        $result = [];
        $result['status'] = false;
        $result['message'] = "something error";

        $users = User::where('staff_id', $r->staff_id)->select(['staff_id', 'time_checkOut', 'location_checkOut'])->first();

        $mytime = Carbon::now();
        $date = $mytime->format('Y-m-d');
        $time = $mytime->format('H:i:s');

        $users->date_checkIn = $date;
        $users->time_checkOut = $time;
        $users->location_checkOut = $r->location_checkOut;

        // Save the updated data to the database
        AttendanceRecord::updateOrCreate(
            ['staff_id' => $users->staff_id, 'date_checkIn' => $date],
            $users->toArray()
        );

        // Retrieve current data
        $currentData = $users->toArray();

        // Store current data into attendace record table
        $attendanceRecord = new AttendanceRecord();
        $attendanceRecord->fill($currentData);
        $attendanceRecord->save();

        $result['data'] = $users;
        $result['status'] = true;
        $result['message'] = "suksess add data";

        return response()->json($result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in function userClockOut:

```
AttendanceRecord::updateOrCreate(
    ['staff_id' => $users->staff_id, 'date_checkIn' => $date],
    $users->toArray()
);
```

and

```
// I suggest you comment these lines
$attendanceRecord = new AttendanceRecord();
$attendanceRecord->fill($currentData);
$attendanceRecord->save();
```

are duplicate codes.

Comment: I forgot to comment out that line. Thanks ! my brain might have been too exhausted yesterday to miss such things. 谢谢！